# Unable to convert String to Double with certain combinations of Region and Language

Tags: ios, swift

I can't convert a String to a Double in certain localizations. Let's say I have the language set to English US and the region to Switzerland.
The string in question is "8,5".

If I use `Double("8,5")` it returns `nil`

If I use

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale.current //it.ch
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    let number2 = formatter.number(from: "8,5")
```

it returns `nil` too

It works if I set the language to English (US) and the region to the United States or say Italian and Italy.

Edit: to clarify the number "8,5" is input using the default keyboard numerical pad in a default textfield

Comment: What do you expect to happen? "8,5" is not valid representation of any double in "IT-CH" - are you executing conversion to return default value of some sort instead of `nil`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if I am using a textfield with a number pad input it uses ",", not "." with IT-CH and English (US). Basically users have to input a number, but some use a different language than their region and Swift doesn't recognize it as a Double

Comment: But for consistency you'll have to switch the decimal separator here as well? (on the number pad/input)

Comment: Gianni if you can't respect user's choice to live there... maybe offer them relocation to IT-IT? :) It is still not clear what you expect to happen when value does not represent double for given Region/Language combination (like "8,5" in IT-CH). @d4Rk proposal sounds reasonable to me - use controls that respect user choices (you may want to clarify why it is not an option by [edit] of the post)

Comment: @d4Rk I am using a default textfield using "decimal pad" as "keyboard type". Isn't the choice to use "." or "," in the decimal pad done by iOS? If not, how can I force the keyboard to use the correct separator?

Comment: Ok if use the system-keypad, I think this should already take the locale into account 0_o

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov but I'm using the default keyboard in a default textfield with "decimal pad" as "keyboard type". Shouldn't the choice of using the correct separator in the default keyboard done by iOS? If not, how can I force the default keyboard to use the correct separator? If users in Switzerland that have set English (US) can input numbers only as "8,5" with the default decimal pad I expect iOS to recognize that "8,5" is a number since it was input with the default number pad in a default textfield

Comment: One possibility to solve such problems is to always convert all `,` to `.` (since in general, these are the only decimal separators used) and then just use POSIX locale for parsing. However, you must be careful because `.` and `,` are used as grouping separators in some languages.

Comment: @Gianni unfortunately I have no idea how iOS deals with inputs. Number formatting is my favorite topic, but I code in .Net/web and know nothing specific about swift/iOS. Asking your users in IT-CH how they input the numbers may be an option (trying it yourself by changing region/language may give you some insights but you may not have defaults they would use)

Comment: @Sulthan good reminder on grouping separators - interpreting 1,500 as 1.5 or 1500 make some difference :)

Comment: @d4Rk yes I thought the same. But If I change the language to English US and the region to the United States I see the dot in default apps such as Health, but not in mine. I think it has something to do with the fact that my app is not localized for English US